# NSSet with dictionaries: Get object by Value of Key

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, enumeration, nsset

I have the following constellation using an NSSet:

```
NSSet {
    NSDictionary {
        "Unique-Identifier-Key": Unique Value
        "Key2": ValueABC
        "Key3": ValueDEF
    }

    NSDictionary {
        "Unique-Identifier-Key": Unique Value
        "Key2": ValueFGH
        "Key3": ValueJKL
    }

    NSDictionary {
        "Unique-Identifier-Key": Unique Value
        "Key2": ValueRST
        "Key3": ValueXYZ
    }
}
```

I'm searching for a way to get one dictionary out of the NSSet by its Unique Value. There are quite a lot NSDictionaries in that NSSet and therefore I'm searching for the way with the best performance.

How about using `(NSSet *)objectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, BOOL *stop))predicate` in the following way?

```
NSString *idSearched = ...;
NSSet *results = [MySet objectsPassingTest:^(id obj,BOOL *stop){
    if ([obj valueForKey:@"Unique-Identifier-Key"] == idSearched) return YES;
    else return NO;
}];
```

Is this the most performant solution? I used NSSet as I read that NSSets have a better performance than NSArrays for finding objects. And I don't need an ordered sequence of the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the actual layout you want is:

```
NSDictionary {
    Unique Value: NSDictionary {
        "Key2": ValueABC
        "Key3": ValueDEF
    }

    Unique Value: NSDictionary {
        "Key2": ValueFGH
        "Key3": ValueJKL
    }

    Unique Value: NSDictionary {
        "Key2": ValueRST
        "Key3": ValueXYZ
    }
}
```

Basically, rather than storing the unique key/value pair inside the dictionary, have a new dictionary where the unique value is the *key* to the other data. If your unique value is an `NSString` then you'll find you'll probably get close to O(1) time complexity.

You can convert your set to the above layout using the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *searchable = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary *dict in MySet)
    [searchable setObject:dict forKey:[dict objectForKey:@"Unique-Identifier-Key"]];
```

(although it would be better to load the data directly into the structure described above rather than converting it from a set). Then, whenever you want to find one of your dictionaries:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [searchable objectForKey:idSearched];
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds quite logical. What if the Unique-Identifier-Key is an object other than NSString (e.g. NSManagedObjectID)? Do I have to convert that key to NSString or will it work with other classes (I read that the class used for key has to adopt NSCopying protocol)? And how about performance when using custom keys?

Comment: @FrankZp: That's correct, keys must adopt to `NSCopying`, but you are already using it in a dictionary, so there shouldn't be any problem. The performance when using custom keys is directly related to the quality of the `hash` method. For most Cocoa types such as `NSString` the `hash` method is pretty good. Absolute worst case scenario is O(n) complexity (which is conceptually no different to how you are searching now) but you still get the benefit of much simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it helps you with performance when you use `NSSet` like that. `NSSet` has better performance than NSArray due to either hash algorithms or some sorting algorithms. If you use a predicate like that, I think the `NSSet` has to search over the whole collection to find the item you need.

I would suggest you create a new class MyObject, that contains your `NSDictionary`, and override the `hash` and `isEqual`

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object;
- (NSUInteger)hash;
```

In the hash, you return your unique value hash and that would improve your performance. But if you have very few objects that you need to search, you may just go with your simple predicate

Comment: What kind of class would MyObject be? A subclass of NSSet?